# Python, How to close excel workbook if user prematurely closes the command prompt?

Tags: python, excel, win32com

Using Windows, I start a command prompt and run my script, which will open an excel file in the background. I do use a try/except/finally block to catch exceptions and finally close the workbook, but it seems that if I hit the red 'X' on the command prompt (before the code completely finishes running) that the excel workbook stays open.

My best guess is that the code just completely stops executing, wherever it was at?

This isn't completely uncommon for me to do. What happens is that I realize I missed a previous step and so I just want to close the command prompt and the workbook that resides in the background.

I initially expected that try/except/finally would cover this case:

```
try:
        xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
        wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=file)
        # Do stuff
        # Close out of command prompt while doing stuff
except Exception as e:
        print(e)
finally:
        wb.Close(SaveChanges=0) # doesn't seem to close out of the workbook 
                                # when command prompt forcefully closed
```

When that failed, I've looked for similar issues elsewhere, and tried the 'atexit' module, which also doesn't seem to work.

What is the correct way to close out of the excel workbook, if the user cancels the command prompt?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do what you want. If you close the command prompt in which the Python program is running, you simply terminate the process. `try...finally` clauses are not honoured, just as functions in the `atexit` chain will not be called. And in most cases, this is what you want. Suppose a program you are running goes into an infinite loop. You would not want to wait for its cleanup processes to be called, because the program might be in such a tight loop that it would never call them.

Comment: Could I possibly spawn a separate (unattached) process, that checks whether the first process still exists? Then if it doesn't, it can check that certain workbooks are closed?

Comment: I think having an unattached process that just closes open workbooks when it sees fit would not be a good idea. You can get most of what you want by moving your code to a GUI environment like `wxWidgets` or `TkInter`. When you close the main window of a GUI program you generally get a callback to give you the chance to close files, say Are you sure?, etc. You can still bypass this and kill the process deliberately using Task Manager, but it is much harder to do it by accident.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see....

```
try:
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=file)
    # Do stuff
    # Close out of command prompt while doing stuff
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
finally:
    wb.Close(SaveChanges=0) # doesn't seem to close out of the workbook 
                            # when command prompt forcefully closed
```

The question needs a little more context but from what I can tell try this:

```
import os

cmd = os.system("start /wait cmd /c {command}")
try:
    xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(Filename=file)
    # Do stuff
    os_close = os.close()
    try:
        os_close
        wb.close(SaveChanges=0)
    except NameError:
        continue

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

The 'finally' doesn't work very well there because the computer does not know when to execute the finally and might not close wb.

Again, **very** little context.